# Why can't I read a keystroke in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

[This simple demo](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Keyboard_Realtime.py) shows how to read keystrokes in PySimpleGUI. But when I attempt to run the [PySimpleGUI Pong demo](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Pong.py), my keystrokes are not noticed as events. Can someone explain why that is?  Thanks.

P.S. Adding `use_default_focus=False` to the PySimpleGUI Pong demo doesn't help.

UPDATE: I found the original Tkinter version of the game. It included

```
    self.canvas.bind_all('w', self.up)
    self.canvas.bind_all('s', self.down)
```

and

```
    self.canvas.bind_all('w', self.up)
    self.canvas.bind_all('s', self.down)
```

at the end of the `__init__` methods in the two `pongbat` classes. (This version doesn't use PySimpleGUI at all.) With this change the PySimpleGUI version version worked also. (But that shouldn't be necessary! It should be possible to get those keystrokes.)

Comment: The PySimpleGUI version isn't reading and processing keystrokes the same way as the demo, so I start debugging that. Do all the keystrokes fail to work, or just ``w`` and ``s`` (I ask because the latter are processed differently than `'Up.'` and `'Down'`).. Seems like you could use the demo to figure-out what values to look for in the game.

Comment: From what I recall of the PySimpleGUI demo, you press the keys to cause movement, not hold them down.  The demo should probably be reworked / revisited as it was posted a long time ago.

Comment: Releasing a key doesn't create an event.

Comment: Just for reference, there's also a demo [here](https://pysimplegui.trinket.io/demo-programs#/examples-for-reddit-posts/navigating-focus).